# How to disable click event on JQuery tabs?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have these simple tabs:

```
<div class="ftabs">                    

<ul id="tabs" class="tabs nav nav-tabs nav-justified" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li  id='an'><a href="#anag" data-toggle="tab"><h3>Dati Anagrafici</h3></a></li>
    <li id='ind'><a href="#indirizzi"  data-toggle="tab"><h3>Indirizzi</h3></a></li>
    <li id='ref'><a href="#referenti" data-toggle="tab"><h3>Referenti</h3></a></li>
    <li id='ban'><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab"><h3>Banche</h3></a></li>
</ul>
```

I can open the tab that I want with jQuery, for example:

```
$("#ref a[href='#referenti']").tab('show');
```

but I would like to disable the first 2 tabs. I've tried it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'disabled', [0, 1]);
```

Why? How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the target tabs directly. Like in this case you can select the first two tabs by $("#an")... and $("#ind")... And then performing the necessary action on it.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AL7bN/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot disable the active tab, so need to set the 3rd tab as active then disable the first two

[From Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-disable):

```
The selected tab cannot be disabled.
```

So

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        active: 2,
        disabled: [0, 1]
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AL7bN/)

To disable the tabs programatically later

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2)
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled", [0, 1]);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HKuKc/)

Comment: @ciaoben can you update the fiddle to replicate the case

Comment: i think i've solved it, i'm testing it now, i'll let you know!

Comment: yes, it works! i am a stupid, i was selecting the id of the <ul> element, not of the div! anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the jquery `index()` (http://api.jquery.com/index/) function. With it you can find out the index of the element you're passing as argument doing like this :

```
//selector could be wrong but you have the use logic
$(".tabs > li").click(function() {
    if ($(".tabs > li").index($(this)) > 1) {
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: if i set a click function on a tab, (i've tried selectors "li", #ind ecc..) it doesn't do anything! why????