# Disable tab click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have `multiple tabs` showing the data as per tab info. What I want is, I want to disable the tabs using Jquery.

Below is the code I am using for it

```
onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {
        var $current = index + 1;           

        if ($current == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if ($current == 2) {
            return ChkValidateSiteDetails();
        }
        if ($current == 3) {
            return btnSiteStatusNext();
        }
        if ($current == 4) {
            return btnExpenseIncurredTab();
        }
        if ($current == 5) {
            return btnExpenseRecurredTab();
        }
        if ($current == 6) {
            return btnAdditionalExpensesTab();
        }
        if ($current == 7) {
            return btnReasonForDropTab();
        }
    }, 
    onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {                       

        var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
        var $current = index + 1;
        var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
        $('#wizard1').find('.progress-bar').css({ width: $percent + '%' });


       /* $('#wizard1 > .steps li').each(function (index) {
            $(this).removeClass('complete');
            index += 1;
            if (index < $current) {
                $(this).addClass('complete');
            }
        }); */

        if ($current >= $total) {
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-next').hide();
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-finish').show();
        } else {
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-next').show();
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-finish').hide();
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-previous').show();
        }
        if ($current == 1) {
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-next').hide();
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-finish').hide();
            $('#wizard1').find('.button-previous').hide();
        }
    }
```

I tried from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516174/how-to-disable-click-event-on-jquery-tabs) but still it was not working for me. How should I disable it.

Comment: Try adding `return false;` as the first line in `onTabClick` i.e. after this line - `onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {`

Comment: Please go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629939/how-to-disable-the-tabs-using-jquery

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj: that was perfectly fine.. Thanks Man..!! you saved my time.